# OpenAPI Swagger Configuration on AWS with Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, swagger, microservices, openapi

I am trying to add Swagger (OpenAPI) in my Spring Boot Application, and configured it in the following way:

My **pom.xml** file has the following dependency:

```
<!-- Swagger UI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

The application class has a **@SpringBootApplication** annotation and the following bean defined:

```
/** Swagger Configuration */
@Bean
public OpenAPI seatManagerOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title("Service API")
                    .description("Some Description")
                    .version("0.0.1")
                    .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")))
            .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                    .description("Some Documentation")
                    .url("https://somelink")
            );
}
```

My Spring Boot Application has a single controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/serviceName")
public class ServiceNameController
```

My **application.yml** has these following additions:

```
springdoc:
  packagesToScan: path.to.service
  pathsToMatch: /serviceName/**
  swagger-ui:
    path: /serviceName/swagger-ui
```

With this very basic configuration, Swagger is working perfectly on my localhost:

[http://localhost:8082/servicename/swagger-ui/index.html]

But when deploying to an ECS cluster on AWS, where my request is passing through a load balancer (ALB) - I get the following error: "Failed to load remote configuration". Inspecting this in the browser, I see a 404 status in the logs and a message:

```
undefined /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

I have a cluster of several micro-services running on ECS. The load balancer directs the various https calls to the relevant target group (service) based on the path, such as:

```
IF Path is /servicename/* AND Host is someHost
Then forward to [relevant target group] (service)
```

I have seen many posts about similar errors, and with answers related to configuration of API gateway (which I am not using at all on AWS) or Spring Security libraries (which I am not using at all).

I tried adding this bean:

```
@Bean
ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
}
```

I also played around with many configurations in my application.yml file, adding and removing many of these properties with various values (not just the ones included down here):

```
springdoc:
#  swagger-ui:
#    use-root-path: false
#    url: "/v3/api-docs"
#    disable-swagger-default-url: true
#    path: /serviceName/swagger-ui
#    configUrl: "/swagger-config.yaml"
#    use-root-path: true
#    urls:
#      url: "/v3/api-docs"
#      name: "seat-manager"
#  api-docs:
#    enabled: true
#    path: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

I also tried adding a **swagger-config.json** file to my resources and to my resources/static folder, and changed the contents back and forth but I couldn't make it work.

What am I missing here? What setting will actually make swagger work remotely in my cloud?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the solution is straight forward. On the ALB you need to expose also the docu json page and later also the api path (for the calls).

To shorted things up: To make swagger work over an ALB the following needs to be exposed:

1. /swagger-ui* -> to access the swagger page
2. /v3/api-docs* -> needed so that the swagger page loads
3. /api* -> needed so that the API calls work